# Why do i get Error http 500.0 when running IIs-express from a folder?

Tags: iis, windows-7, webmatrix, iis-express

I am trying to run the iis-express command tool from a folder :

```
iis-express /path:. /trace.
```

i have the admin rights , and my folder only contains a index.html file.
when i try to do it that way , all i get is an http Error 500.0 error. If i try to open the folder with webmatrix , then run the website , it works though , any suggestions ? where can i read the logs on my Windows 7 pc too ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIS Express (iisexpress.exe) does not expand current directory when you pass '.' as value for /path switch. Instead of '.', provide full path to the content directory.

```
iisexpress.exe /path:<full-path-to-content-directory>
```

You can find logs in %userprofile%\documents\iisexpress\ directory (in 'logs' and 'TraceLogFiles' folders)
Note: When iisexpress.exe is started from command line, it will be named as 'Development Web Site'.

Comment: it worked thanks. do you think it is possible to enable php from the command line too ?

Comment: No... it does not work, but you can make it work by adding php settings in the applicationhost.config file (this template is used when iisexpress.exe is used from command line) located in %programfiles%\iis express\config\appserver folder.